# how to use cordova plugin in app

Tags: android, cordova

I'm developing a cordova plugin for reading mp3 metadata in android, I have gotten the plugin installed in my app but when I try to call the cordova.exec plugin I get a console error that says "MediaMeta is not defined".
My plugin is here: https://github.com/stlouisweb/mediaMetadata
and in my app I'm trying to access it here:

```
function getMetaData(fullpath) {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    var fullpath = fullpath;
    var success = function(trackinfo)
    {
       // result = JSON.stringify(result);
        console.log(trackinfo);
       // data.push(JSON.parse(result));
    };
    var error = function(message) { alert("Metadata received unsuccessfully: " + message); };
    MediaMeta.createEvent(fullpath, success, error);

})
```

}

Comment: Updated the github repo. I'm not getting the console error any more, but device logs show error installing the plugin.

Comment: You should also not clobber into the window namespace. Put the namespace in `cordova.plugins`

Comment: can you please elaborate on the clobber, I'm not sure what to put here. My plugin is com.stlouisweb.mediametadata, do I put that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating `plugin.xml` like this:

CHANGE:

```
<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0"
    id="com.stlouisweb.mediametadata"
    version="0.1.0">
```

TO:

```
<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    id="com.stlouisweb.mediametadata"
    version="0.1.0">
```

The reason being that for Cordova to modify the Android config this XML needs to be namespaced for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to the clobber question

```
<js-module src="www/mediaMetadata.js" name="MediaMetadata">
    <clobbers target="window.Media" />
</js-module>
```

to

```
<js-module src="www/mediaMetadata.js" name="MediaMetadata">
    <clobbers target="cordova.plugins.media" />
</js-module>
```

and change your documentation, examples etc. to use `cordova.plugins.media`